# Android: How do you play a sound at a volume unaffected by any of the Android system volumes (ringtone, media, etc)?

Tags: java, android

I'd like to play a sound from a (ringtone) URI in my Android application. However, I would like to play this sound at an arbitrary volume and not have system volumes, such as Media and Ringtone volume, affect playback.

I've been paging through the API docs, but I'm at a loss. Is this possible with Android and if so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe most apps aiming to do this choose a stream type, stash the current volume level (using [`AudioManager.getStreamVolume`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamVolume%28int%29)), set that volume to whatever they want it to be (using [`setStreamVolume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29) to some percentage of [`getStreamMaxVolume`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamMaxVolume%28int%29)), and then restore the stashed volume level after playback completes. But think hard before you do this -- unless you're creating a "find my lost phone" app, there's rarely a reason to ignore the user's requested volume levels, and you run a high risk of irritating someone silencing their phone for a meeting.

Comment: Actually "find my phone" is a pretty similar use-case. I'm writing an app where certain emergency calls would ring at full volume, even if the phone is on "silent."

Comment: Not only might you "risk...irritating someone" by simply changing it for your event, but if you screw up and fail to reset it, it will remain at the higher volume until the user goes in and fixes it, which may not make them happy.